# Software Suitable for Expanding and Integrating Long Algebraic Expressions

Tags: math-software

Does anyone know if available software packages can cope with very long algebraic expressions which may involve hundreds or thousands of terms.

For example here is a (prettified) example input to a homemade VB6 program which performs addition, multiplication, simple integration and binomial expansion:-

```
{@PRODUCT!
    ([V])
    ({@SUM!         
        ([V*h]+[-g*h]) 
        ({@PRODUCT! 
            ([(1/2)]) 
            ([V*h]+[-g*h])
            ([-3*e^2]+[E^2])
            ([V^-2])
            ({@BINOMEXPAND!
                ([1]+[-2*g*V^-1]+[g^2*V^-2]+[h^2*V^-2]);(<-1>)
             })
         })
    })
    ({@SUM!
        ([e^2*E^-2])
        ({@PRODUCT!
            ([2*e*V^-1])
            ({@BINOMEXPAND! ([1]+[-2*g*V^-1]+[g^2*V^-2]+[h^2*V^-2]);(<-1/2>)})  })
            ({@PRODUCT!
                ([E^2*V^-2])
                ({@BINOMEXPAND!([1]+[-2*g*V^-1]+[g^2*V^-2]+[h^2*V^-2]);(<-1>)})
             })
         })
         ({@BINOMEXPAND!
            ([1]
            {@PRODUCT!
                ([2*e*V^-1])
                ({@BINOMEXPAND!([1]+[-2*g*V^-1]+[g^2*V^-2]+[h^2*V^-2]);(<-1/2>)})
            }
            {@PRODUCT!
                ([E^2*V^-2])
                ({@BINOMEXPAND!([1]+[-2*g*V^-1]+[g^2*V^-2]+[h^2*V^-2]);(<-1>)})
            }
            );(<-1>)
          })
    })
}
{INTEGRATE: e>E}
{CULL RULE: "Exclude all terms with E power <1}
```

The program is becoming difficult to maintain and great care is needed to format the input correctly as errors are not always detected and spurious answers can result. So I would like to consider moving to a capable software package.  But so far, I cannot tell, without digging deep, what packages might be capable of this size of problem.

Comment: This isn't really a question about mathematics per se, so I am voting to close.

Comment: @Math1000 Apologies if subject is out of scope. Looking at the panel on the RHS of (my) page there are plenty of questions asking for software recommendations.

Comment: @Math1000 also there is actually a tag for math-software. So I dont understand why my question is not suitable.

Comment: Very well, I will retract my vote. I would recommend Mathematica but it does not seem to play nicely with extremely complicated expressions. I am not experienced with any other commercial CAS software so I am afraid I cannot help you here.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks.